# MYSQL - day with the most birthdays on average

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So im trying to to get the name of the day when on average most people are born. 
I did this:

```
select dayname(People.birth) as day, count(*)
from People
group by dayname(People.birth)
group by count(*) desc
```

but this basically just returns dayname of the date when most people were born. What I need, is to take from each week the day when most people were born, and return the day that is most common from all the weeks. (for example: it returns monday because on mondays most people are born. Not saturday, because there is just one saturday when a lot of people were born). btw the table with people looks like this: p.id, p.name, p.weight, p.birthdate

Comment: Then add week to the  grouping.

Comment: I think when you need to select day in the first place, you need to use "DAYOFWEEK()" function, then you can count by result of this function, this should be working. Like "SELECT DAYOFWEEK(People.birth) as day ... your code"

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

If you want the day-of-week for each week, then you can use:

```
select t.*
from (select year(p.birth) as yr, week(p.birth) as week, dayname(p.birth) as day, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by year(p.birth), week(p.birth) order by count(*) desc
      from People p
      group by yr, week, day
     ) yw
where seqnum = 1;
```